# Can't catch error in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, try-catch, throw

I have some code like blow, 
if throw 1, display will be

```
catch in main
throw 1
```

if throw 2, display will be

```
catch in test
throw 2
```

but if I want display like this,

```
catch in test
throw 2
catch in main
throw 2
```

how can I do?

```
function test(database)
{
  if(1) throw 'throw 1';   //if throw at here, 'catch in main' will display
  var col=database.collection('profiles');
  col.findOne({"oo" : 'xx'})
  .then(function(doc){
      throw 'throw 2';  //if throw at here, 'catch in main' will [NOT] display
  })
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log('catch in test');
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  });
}

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, database) {
  try{
    test(database);
  }catch(e){
    console.log('catch in main');  //if throw 2, this line will [NOT] run
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use promises (and you're in this case), there's little use of wrapping the client code in `try-catch`. What you should do is 1) return a promise from `test` function; 2) subscribe on the returning promise' reject with `catch` method. One possible approach:

```
// in test()
return col.findOne({"oo" : 'xx'})
.then(function(doc){
  throw 'throw 2';  //if throw at here, 'catch in main' will [NOT] display
})
.catch(function(e){
  console.log('catch in test');
  console.log(e);
  throw e; // 
});

// in main:
function handleError(e) {
  console.log('catch in main');
  console.log(e);
}

// ...
try {
  test(database).catch(handleError);
} catch(e) {
  handleError(e);
}
```

By the way, it seems to me your first example (with throwing in your own code) is artificial (introduced only to make sure `try-catch` in general works), and in your real case it's only DB functions that might end with an error. If I'm correct, you might want to get rid of that `try-catch` block completely: promise `.catch` handler will be enough.